# First android app. Should I use the 2.3.3 version of the honeycomb?

Tags: android

So I`m about to write my first android app. I want it to be able to run on a handset but also on a tablet.

My question is, when I create an Android in Eclipse, which SDK should I choose? My initial thought is to write with 2.3.3 SDK. I imagine I should be able to run it on honeycomb as well, or I will have to write the same app but using the 3.0 SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the android [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), you should be able to build against android versions all the way down to 1.6 and still support tablets. You can write a single application and support all devices from 1.6 and up (including tablets). I generally write applications that target 2.1, since that's the lowest version number that still [has a significant market share](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html). By using the Support Package, I can write a single application that is accessible by the vast majority of the android market and still works on the latest and greatest as well as uses some of the features that weren't introduced to the API until much later than 2.1.

Comment: I see what if I already started with 2.3.3. Is there a way to easily change the target to 2.1 in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. See my answer for changing the target in the manifest file. You might also need to change the library to the android 2.1 library, but I'm unsure about that.

Comment: yeah i was curious about libraries because it using the 2.3.3. So i was wondering is there an easy way to switch the target sdk easily with eclipse that automatically change the librairies to 2.1. Im also a noob with eclpise...

Comment: If you right click the project and open properties... click on 'Android' on the left to open that tab. You can change the build target there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you target Android 2.1 unless you really need some API that is introduced in a newer version. This targets [almost all users](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) (tablet, etc. will be able to run it too). If you want to take advantage of the bigger screen of tablets in different layouts, you can use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) from [the compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this statistics: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

I would suggest to use version 2.2

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the features that you want to utilize in your app. There are three settings that you can set in the application manifest after creating your app:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
      android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

These allow you to control what OS version your app will be available on. A rule of thumb for now is that most apps are workable on future versions of the OS. For example, an app developed for 2.1 will work on 3.0, but you will not be able to utilize and 3.0-specific features in your app then.

Check out [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)